# How to print a vector of vector? error shows this "no matching function for call to ‘begin(std::vector<Arc*>**&)"

Tags: c++, vector

I want to print this vector `vector< vector< Arc * > * > _adjacences;`

when I do

```
for (auto j : _adjacences[i])
   cout << " --> " << j ;
```

an error shows saying this

```
no matching function for call to ‘begin(std::vector<Arc*>**&)’
   for (auto j : &_adjacences[i])
```

What can i do ?

Comment: Something like `for (auto j : _adjacences[i]) for (auto k : *j) cout << " --> " << k;`?

Comment: same error shows up

Comment: Since the pointers are confusing you maybe write the code without pointers `vector<vector<Arc>> _adjacences;`? Of course it's impossible for me to say if that's a good idea or not, but I do know that many newbies use pointers where they have no useful purpose.

Comment: `_adjacences[i]` is `vector< Arc * > *`, so `for (auto j : *_adjacences[i]) cout << " --> " << j ;`?

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the error you show. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], and then copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question.

Comment: If someone told you that you need to write `new` in C++, they are mistaken.

Comment: By the way, why are you using pointers to vectors? Pointers to containers are rarely if ever needed. And unless `Arc` is a polymorphic type you  might not need pointers to it either.

Comment: @MikeCAT You got it, it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to print a vector of vector?
>
> ```
> vector< vector< Arc * > * > _adjacences;
> ```

That's not a vector of vectors. That's a vector of pointers (to vectors).

> ```
> for (auto j : &_adjacences[i])
> ```

The problem here is that you attempt a for-each loop on a pointer to pointer to vector. That's not possible.

If you want to iterate over the vector pointed by `_adjacences[i]`, then you have to indirect through that pointer:

```
for (auto j : *_adjacences[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is entirely unclear why the vector is declared like

```
vector< vector< Arc * > * > _adjacences;
```

instead of

```
vector< vector< Arc * >> _adjacences;
```

The type of the expression `_adjacences[i]` is `vector<Arc *> *`.

So this for loop

```
for (auto j : _adjacences[i])
   cout << " --> " << j ;
```

because there is no functions begin and end for pointers.

You should write at least like

```
for (auto j : *_adjacences[i])
   cout << " --> " << j ;
```

In this case the type of `j`  will be `Arc *`. That is this loop tries to output pointers.